# Postgres SQL - select inconsistent date formats from character field

Tags: postgresql, date, format, sqldatatypes

I'm stuck on a date formatting issue and hoping someone can help me out!

Our DB has a date field which was formatted as a character field by our programming team because of different import sources/formats.

I am ideally aiming to create a view which ends up with date only which I will then use in the reporting tool (dbxtra) for daily/monthly grouping on pivots and reports.

Example data:

"2015-05-30"

"3/06/2015 12:00 AM"

I have tried:

- converting to date with ::date
- substr to take first 10 characters

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have also tried: trim(both ' ' from substr(comp_date,1,10)) as comp_date2 which now gives me the date part only without spaces.... although still no good

Comment: Use `to_timestamp`. Since the formats vary within a column, you'll probably need a `CASE` statement that tries different formats. It's going to be slow and ugly. I suggest whacking your programming team firmly about the head.

Comment: And once you have cleaned up the mess, change the column to `timestamp`

Answer (score 0):

I would write a stored procedure for this which you can call in your sql query. Something like this (pseudo code):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION convertMessedUpStringsToDate(i_val1 varchar) RETURNS timestamp
declare 
  retval timestamp;
  formatArray varchar[];
begin
  -- build array with possible formats, most used in front
  formatArray[0] = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
  formatArray[1] = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI AM';

  for i in 0 .. formatArray.count loop
    begin
      retval = to_timestamp(i_val, formatArray[i]);
    exception
      -- catch any exception and try the next format
    end;
  end loop;

  return retval;
end;
```

Another option is to parse your input using a regex and find the matching pattern that way. Anyway I hope you don't have too many different patterns.